# How can I measure bacterial alkaline phosphatase activity?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

I want to measure alkaline phosphatase activity using PNPP in my mutant bacteria strains, but all the protocols I found involve purification of the phosphatase (which I have no need of).

Does anyone know a good protocol which involves using only the supernatant, without purification of the enzyme? What is the preferred buffer for the reaction?

Answer (score 3):

I found this [kit](http://www.anaspec.com/products/product.asp?id=50319) that appears to be compatible with biological samples.  Rather than buying the kit you may also be able to imitate / modify their [protocol](http://www.anaspec.com/servePdf.asp?f=72146.pdf&t=datasheet) to do the assay with your super natant.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I can imitate the kit - they don't share the components of the buffers. It did give me some idea of how the protocol is done, so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a paper from 1973 describing a very simple protocol:

[**Wolf PL, Von der Muehll E, Praisler K**. 1973. A test for bacterial alkaline phosphatase: use in rapid identification of Serratia organisms. Clinical chemistry 19: 1248–9.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/4758599)